# what should the ACL value be when limiting S3 object access to CloudFront only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I followed https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

But I cannot figure out what should the ACL on AWS.S3.PutObjectRequest be when I upload to s3 bucket. 
Possible values:
"private"|"public-read"|"public-read-write"|"authenticated-read"|"aws-exec-read"|"bucket-owner-read"|"bucket-owner-full-control"

Using JavaSript SDK Currently I have "public-read", I know I should change this, but I am not sure which is the best for this case. My initial thought is to "private".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`private` is correct, though not strictly necessary, since that's the default behavior.  Specifying no ACL or specifying the "private" canned ACL is exactly the same.

> private | Bucket and object    | Owner gets FULL_CONTROL. No one else has access rights (default).
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl

"No one else has access rights" actually means *No one else has access rights granted by the ACL* since the bucket owner can grant access to objects it owns using the bucket policy (or IAM user/role policies, though that isn't applicable to an Origin Access Identity, which is granted access via the bucket policy).